# Auto scaling in amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I want to know how auto scaling in amazon ec2 works. I mean lets say I have a huge burst in request then it will automatically launch a new instance. But I initially set up the database and server code in the first instance. So, how does it go to the next instance. Further, if we  get a request, how will it be distributed to the new instance. I want to know about this. I have the database in the first instance. Will it be replicated in all of them so that the same  information is sent to the users.

Answer (score 1):

Your database server should not be load balanced or auto-scaled, unless the data on it never changes. Load balancing and auto-scaling work best when used as web/app servers that can communicate to a single DB back-end instance.

Comment: Yeah, but will my server code be replicated automatically. Lets say I have a website in one instance. So to balance the load, adding further instances, will the web site code be automatically replicated in all the instances?

Comment: When you set up Auto-scaling, you give it an AMI and when Amazon spins up new instances, it creates them from that AMI. Here are the steps you would take:1.) Set up your web server in it's entirety. 2.) Shut down that web server ( You need to use EBS to not lose your data). 3.) Make an AMI of that server. 4.) Configure Auto-scaling to use that AMI

Comment: @BNicoll It's generally preferable to provision-at-boot than to create a new AMI.  Otherwise you're creating a new AMI after every minor code change and you're taking the exit ramp off of Amazon's rolling release schedule (meaning you have to now maintain your own AMI--security patches, updates, etc).  If provisioning at boot isn't  fast enough, use something like Netflix's Bakeri (though I don't know if that's been released to the public yet).

Answer (score 0):

To enable auto scaling you need to understand the concept of spot fleets and spot request.
Then create a load balancer and a security group.

Once you have understand these terms you can configure / implement procedure for auto scaling.